# Logging requests and responses in express middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, logging

I'm trying to implement a logger in an [Express](http://expressjs.com) application. I need it to be able to log requests and the response (status code and body) sent back for each request. I started writing a middleware that looks like this:

```
function (req, res, next) {
    ...
    res.on('finish', function () {
       Logger.debug('For request', req);
       Logger.debug('Response sent');
    });
    ...
}
```

I need to access the data passed to the `res` object method used to send the response. For example, if in one controller I had:

```
res.json({ foo: 'bar' })
```

I need a way to get that `{ foo: 'bar' }` object, something like this maybe:

```
function (req, res, next) {
    ...
    res.on('finish', function () {
       Logger.debug('For request', req);
       var data = res.data; // or res.body, or whatever
       Logger.debug('Response: ' + res.statusCode, data);
    });
    ...
}
```

Is there any property or method in the Express `res` object that I could use for that? Or, is there a better strategy for logging requests and the responses for them?

Comment: There are various modules that you can use to get your hands on the response body, for instance [`express-interceptor`](https://github.com/axiomzen/express-interceptor).

Answer (score 8):

You need an event listener that will be triggered when response.end (or send) methods are called. **Express doesn't have such listener but node.js raw api does have.**

There is [a `finish` event in node.js http server instances](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_finish) which makes you able to do things after you sent your response to the client.

You can easily integrate with your existing Express server:

```
response.on('finish', () => {
  // Do your logging here.
});
```

I recommend that save your logs in a javascript object during request and send them inside of finish event's callback when response has sent.

Comment: I tried this to add as middleware to log the request but the request got stuck.

Answer (score 5):

I found an existing module, [morgan-body](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan-body) that accomplishes what you're trying to do.

Here's how you'd use the middleware, per the documentation:

```
const morganBody = require('morgan-body');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

// must parse body before morganBody as body will be logged
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// hook morganBody to express app (Unlike typical express middleware you're passing the actual app into the function)
morganBody(app);
```

This answer could be useful if you want to use an out of the box solution or are looking for some reference points on how to implement it yourself.

Comment: this is just ugly. It could work. But is still a non-pattern