# Add a logger to log information for response and request from a server (express and nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, logging, middleware

My server will post data to another server, is there any way that I can add logger and log the response and request data thanks

```
const request = require('request');

requestIotPlatform = function requestIotPlatform(req, res, next) {

    var formData = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    var form = {
        data_in: formData
    };
    var uri = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    var headers = {
        'Authorization': authBase64,
        //'Content-Length': form.length,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive', 
        'charset': 'utf-8'
    };
    
    request.post({
        headers: headers,       
        uri: uri,
        form: form
    }, function (err, response, body) {
        console.log(response.statusCode)
    });
    next();
}

module.exports = { requestIotPlatform };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logging requests and responses in express middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37578982/logging-requests-and-responses-in-express-middleware)

Answer (score 0):

I use this module, basically it's a middleware for logging request/responses in Express apps: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-requests-logger